# Atomically update a file, preserving metadata

Tags: file-io, filesystems

I'm writing a text editor, and I'm atomically writing files to disk using `fwrite`  to temp file and `rename`. That's fine, but I lose data like permissions, ownership and presumably any extended attributes.

Is there a way to reliably atomically update a file while preserving metadata?

Comment: What platform and file system are you targeting?

Comment: OSX (HFS+) and Linux (ext3/4) are the only ones I really care about.

Comment: cant you set permissions/attributes on the temp file before you rename?

Comment: @sbridges sure, but I worry that I'll miss something...

Comment: It was ages ago, but can you remember what the actual answer was?

Comment: @Sz. I don't believe I ever found a good answer for this!